# why can't .gitignore prevent others from editing files

Tags: github, lua

I have a library of code on Github but I don't want someone to accidentally edit them so I installed .gitignore to prevent others from editing them. But it doesn't prevent editing, it just prevents others from adding files.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A `.gitignore` file doesn't prevent changes to files, and it has no effect on files that are already tracked by Git.  The [Git FAQ is very clear that there's no way to ignore changes to tracked files](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).  The FAQ explains alternatives for common situations, and why suggestions to use `git update-index` for that purpose don't work.

Even if you could do that, a user could just copy the files elsewhere and edit them and then add them back using one of the plumbing commands.  Once someone has the code, they're able to edit it in whatever way they want; if you don't want them to modify the files, then either don't distribute them, or distribute them only under a license that prevents them from making modifications.